# What does "<=>" in MySQL mean?

Tags: mysql, null, operators, equality

What does `<=>` in MySQL mean and do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this operator <=> in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql)

Comment: This one is 3 years older...

Comment: that one has 6x more views and 2x answers. SO is a strange place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) says it all:

> NULL-safe equal. This operator
>   performs an equality comparison like
>   the = operator, but returns 1 rather
>   than NULL if both operands are NULL,
>   and 0 rather than NULL if one operand
>   is NULL.

```
mysql> select NULL <=> NULL;
+---------------+
| NULL <=> NULL |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select NULL = NULL;
+-------------+
| NULL = NULL |
+-------------+
|        NULL |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select NULL <=> 1;
+------------+
| NULL <=> 1 |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select NULL = 1;
+----------+
| NULL = 1 |
+----------+
|     NULL |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the [NULL-safe equal operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

The difference between <=> and = is when one or both of the operands are NULL values. For example:

```
NULL <=> NULL gives True
NULL = NULL   gives NULL
```

Here is the full table for the `<=>` comparison of values 1, 2 and NULL:

```
     |  1      2    NULL
-----+-------------------
1    | True   False False
2    | False  True  False
NULL | False  False True
```

Compare to the ordinary equality operator:

```
     |  1      2    NULL
-----+-------------------
1    | True   False NULL
2    | False  True  NULL
NULL | NULL   NULL  NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

NULL-safe equal to operator

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Answer (score 2):

`<=>` is a so called [`NULL`-safe-equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

```
SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL; 
-> 1, 1, 0

SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
-> 1, NULL, NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as SQL standard keyword DISTINCT

```
SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE `address1` is not distinct from `address2`
```