# What is this operator <=> in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, spaceship-operator

I'm working on code written by a previous developer and in a query it says,

```
WHERE p.name <=> NULL
```

What does `<=>` mean in this query? Is it something equal to `=`? Or is it a syntax error?

But it is not showing any errors or exceptions. I already know that `<>` = `!=` in [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

Comment: the `spaceship` operator

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi, We [need](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3C%3D%3E) a google that allows us to google for operators directly.

Comment: @Pacerier - i found this, some 5ish years ago http://symbolhound.com (dunno if there's a better alternative)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It's the [`NULL` safe equal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator.

Like the regular `=` operator, two values are compared and the result is either `0` (not equal) or `1` (equal); in other words: `'a' <=> 'b'` yields `0` and `'a' <=> 'a'` yields `1`.

Unlike the regular `=` operator, values of `NULL` don't have a special meaning and so it never yields `NULL` as a possible outcome; so: `'a' <=> NULL` yields `0` and `NULL <=> NULL` yields `1`.

#### Usefulness

This can come in useful when both operands may contain `NULL` and you need a consistent comparison result between two columns.

Another use-case is with prepared statements, for example:

```
... WHERE col_a <=> ? ...
```

Here, the placeholder can be either a scalar value or `NULL` without having to change anything about the query.

#### Related operators

Besides `<=>` there are also two other operators that can be used to compare against `NULL`, namely `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`; they're part of the ANSI standard and therefore supported on other databases, unlike `<=>`, which is MySQL-specific.

You can think of them as specialisations of MySQL's `<=>`:

```
'a' IS NULL     ==> 'a' <=> NULL
'a' IS NOT NULL ==> NOT('a' <=> NULL)
```

Based on this, your particular query (fragment) can be converted to the more portable:

```
WHERE p.name IS NULL
```

#### Support

The SQL:2003 standard introduced a predicate for this, which works exactly like MySQL's `<=>` operator, in the following form:

```sql
IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM
```

The following is universally supported, but is relative complex:

```sql
CASE WHEN (a = b) or (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL)
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END = 1
```

Comment: So then what is the use of `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` ??

Comment: so it means there is no difference? and this `<=>` is somewhat a useless operator? right?

Comment: @zzlalani Not at all; `<=>` takes two operands whereas `IS (NOT) NULL` only takes one; **big** difference ... it's as useful as `=` itself in that respect.

Comment: @zzlalani `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` are in the SQL standard. `<=>` is a MySQL specific extension.

Comment: So, like the `is not distinct from` operator. Curious to know if MySQL can use an index on that...

Comment: @Denis it should, because it's just like doing normal equality with an OR condition. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956408/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-and)

Comment: @Ja͢ck,  Is there a `>=<` operator for the inverse of `<=>` ?

Comment: @Pacerier No, the inverse of `a <=> b` is `NOT(a <=> b)`.

Comment: @zzlalani, The spaceship operator is **actually very useful**. It's as useful as `=` in "normal" programming languages and maths. `a = b` is either `true` or `false`, except in SQL land they managed to brainwash the [population there](http://goo.gl/mzihcp) that it can also be `null`, and to everyone else it just doesn't make any sense. Indeed, the whole land of Java, C#, Javascript, PHP, etc, would revolt if `null == null` give you something besides `true`. Even something [as wrong as Javascript](http://goo.gl/rM6e0f) knows that `undefined == undefined` = `true`.

Answer (score 66):

is **<=>** `NULL-safe equal to operator`

This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

See here for the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

Sample :

you should use IS NOT NULL. (The comparison operators = and <> both give UNKNOWN with NULL on either side of the expression.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL;
```

can also negate the null safe equality operator but this is not standard SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE NOT (YourColumn <=> NULL);
```

Comment: Correction: `<=>` should be called the [equals operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql#comment47483870_21928508) and `=` is the `NULL` unsafe equals operator.

Answer (score 32):

It is the **[NULL-safe equal to operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)**

<=> Operator is used to compare NULL values with the fields. If normal =(equals) Operators return NULL if one of the comparison value is NULL. With <=> operator returns true or false. <=> Operator is same as IS NULL.

From the manual:-

> `<=>` performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns
>   1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL
>   if one operand is NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

**Edit:-**(*Although very late to add one important side note mentioning **NOT <=>** as well*)

**On a side note:-**

## NOT <=>

There is one more point **NOT <=>** which is used to compare NULL values with the fields. If normal != or <> (not equals) Operators return NULL if one of the comparison value is NULL. With NOT applied to <=> operator returns true or false. NOT applied to <=> Operator is same as IS NOT NULL.

**Example:-**

```
SELECT NULL != NULL,         //--Result is NULL
   NOT NULL <=> NULL,        //--Result is 0
   NULL IS NOT NULL;         //--Result is 0
```

Comment: `NOT <=>` is not an operator, it's `NOT` applied to the result of `op1 <=> op2`.

Comment: @Jack:- Yes you are correct. Updated the answer! Added that so as to make a point :)

Comment: So I guess there's no `<!=>` operator

Comment: @kip: no there is not!

Answer (score 21):

`<=>` is MySQL's null-safe "equal to" operator.  [**From the manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

> NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

Comment: thank you for a correct resourceful reputable response! :)

Answer (score 16):

`<=>` is the [NULL-safe equal operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to). It is equivalent to the standard SQL `is not distinct from` operator. Its behavior is best explained via truth table:

| a | b | a <=> b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | false |
| 1 | 1 | true |
| 1 | null | false* |
| null | null | true* |

* Notice that this operator will never return unknown (represented by null) unlike other operators.

Answer (score 12):

NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

**It significance:**

When you compare a NULL value with a non-NULL value, you'll get NULL. If you want to check if a value is null.

The Equality operator(<=>) which considers NULL as a normal value, so it returns 1 (not NULL) if both values are NULL and returns 0 (not NULL) if one of the values is NULL:

**eg**

```
 SELECT NULL <=> NULL -- 1
 SELECT TRUE <=> TRUE -- 1
 SELECT col1 <=> col2 FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 10):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

> NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but **returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.**

An example using the `<=>` operator would be:

```
SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
```

Which would return:

```
1, 1, 0
```

An example of the regular `=` operator would be:

```
SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
```

Which would return:

```
1, NULL, NULL
```

The `<=>` operator is very similar to the `=` operator, except `<=>` will never return `NULL`

Answer (score 4):

It is the NULL - Safe Equal to operator. Check [description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t JOIN t2 WHERE t2.ids = t.ids;
+----+------+----+------+
| id | ids  | id | ids  |
+----+------+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |  2 |    2 |
|  5 |    6 |  5 |    6 |
|  6 |    7 |  6 |    7 |
+----+------+----+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t JOIN t2 WHERE t2.ids <=> t.ids;
+----+------+----+------+
| id | ids  | id | ids  |
+----+------+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |  2 |    2 |
|  3 | NULL |  3 | NULL |
|  4 | NULL |  3 | NULL |
|  3 | NULL |  4 | NULL |
|  4 | NULL |  4 | NULL |
|  5 |    6 |  5 |    6 |
|  6 |    7 |  6 |    7 |
```

Answer (score -2):

The difference between `operand1=operand2` and `operand1<=>operand2` is that the prior will return `null`  while any of the two operands are null.
But the latter return `1` or `0` depends on the operands' value even if null.

As a contrast:

- `select null = null`, return `null` ; but `select null <=> null`,return `1`
- `select null = 'abc'`,return `null`; but `select null <=> 'abc'`,return `0`

Comment: False. It does not always return true if col1 is null! try `SELECT null <=> 'a'`

Comment: I have corrected it, thanks for your pointing out the problem.