# Is there an equivalent in MS SQL Server to the <=> operator in MySQL?

Tags: sql-server, equivalence

I was just reading this question, about `<=>` in MySQL:

[What is this operator <=> in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql)

Is there an equivalent to this for SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no anything like that built-in into SQL Server but you can use `ISNULL`, for example:

```
DECLARE @value1 AS VARCHAR(10) = 'a'
DECLARE @value2 AS VARCHAR(10) = NULL
DECLARE @nullreplace AS VARCHAR(10) = ''

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(@value1,@nullreplace) = ISNULL(@value2,@nullreplace) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

The problem with that is you need to select a value for NULL replacement that is not going to appear in the values you compare.

Answer (score 1):

As was said, there's no direct operator.  You might do something like this - replace

`WHERE field <=> 'a'`
with

`WHERE IsEqual(field,'a')`, where IsEqual is a user function...

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsEqual( A VARCHAR(128), B VARCHAR(128) ) RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN
    IF (( A = B ) IS NULL) THEN
        RETURN ((A IS NULL) AND (B IS NULL));
    ELSE
        RETURN (A = B);
    END IF;
END
```