# Comparing NULL value in MYSql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a condition in where clause like:

```
LocationId=IFNULL(LocId,LocationId)
```

here LocId is NULL so by IFNUll its returning LocationId which is Also Null in this case this query is not returning anything.
Please tell me the solution for it.

Comment: Please add your query, sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [null safe comparison](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator:

```
LocationId <=> IFNULL(LocId, LocationId)
```

The difference between the regular `=` operator is that the `null` value is not treated as special, e.g. if both left and right hand argument are `null` it will yield `1`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql/21928508#21928508) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

mysql NULL is not equal to NULL, check here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also
>   NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.
>
> In MySQL, 0 or NULL means false and anything else means true. The
>   default truth value from a boolean operation is 1.

so, your logic should be like this:

```
select ...
from ...
where
(
    (LocId is null and LocationId is null)
    OR
    (LocId is not null and LocationId = LocId)
)
```

you can write it shorter, usually Ids are positive values, so you could compare:

```
select ...
from ...
where
ifnull(LocId, -1) = ifnull(LocationId, -1)
```

UPDATE: in mysql also exists non ansi standard [null-safe comparison](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), which is shorter, check @Ja͢ck answer

Comment: IFNULL(E.LocationId,-1)=COALESCE(LocId,E.LocationId,-1)
i used this for my solution and its giving me the expected result.Thanks

Comment: @ManishKumar yeah, if you need to return all values in case of null locid

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that you cannot use any [relational operator with NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html).

The only option is to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` or the  `<=>`

So you need to try like this:

```
LocId IS NULL and LocationId IS NULL
OR
LocId IS NOT NULL and LocationId = LocId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It:

```
LocationId=IFNULL(LocId,LocationId)
AND LocationId IS NOT NULL
```

Or

```
LocationId=COALESCE(LocId,LocationId)
```