# MySQL IF logic inside trigger with NEW and OLD

Tags: mysql

Apologies for the vague title - hopefully this explains better:

The below trigger is firing after an update (as designed) but the two `IF` statements are firing when neither the `prospectid` or `propertyid` fields are updated.

So the first question is, is there something wrong with the `IF` logic? I do recall having some issues with `<>` vs `<=>`...?

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrig AFTER UPDATE ON t_enquiries
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.prospectid <=> OLD.prospectid) OR (NEW.propertyid <=> OLD.propertyid) THEN
    IF (NEW.prospectid IS NOT NULL) AND (NEW.propertyid IS NOT NULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO t_prospect_property_link (prospectid, propertyid, remaininginspections) VALUES (NEW.prospectid, NEW.propertyid, 10)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE subscribed = 1, remaininginspections = 10;
    END IF;
END IF;
END
```

If my `IF` statements are ok, surely this statement which fires the trigger isn't causing the `prospectid` and `propertyid` fields to do something to make the `IF` evaluate true???

```
UPDATE t_enquiries SET recordstatus = 3, enquirystatus = 1 WHERE id = xxx;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this operator <=> in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<>` is a "not equal to" comparison operator.  `a <> b` will evaluate to TRUE when a and b are both non-NULL and are not equal to each other.

`<=>` (spaceship) operator is the null-safe equality comparison operator.

`a <=> b` is shorthand for  `( a = b OR ( a IS NULL AND b IS NULL ))`

Once we have a good handle on SQL tri-valued boolean logic (TRUE, FALSE, NULL), the operators should not present any difficulty.

One area that can be confusing is the order of precedence of the operators. But fortunately, that is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html

We can use parens to override the order of precedence, which we frequently need to do when both `OR` and `AND` operators are involved.

---

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, so we're just guessing.

Maybe you are wanting to check that value of a column has *changed*.

```
IF NOT NEW.col <=> OLD.col THEN
   -- value of col has changed
END IF;
```

Comment: Solved by understanding the spaceship and inserting that `NOT`. Thanks!