# What is the function of operator <<,>> and <=> in mysql

Tags: mysql

<<,>> and <=> when these operators are used.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql

Comment: >>, << is it a comparison operator ?

Comment: @BLPraveen Did you read the links? `<<` and `>>` are no comparison operators.

Answer (score 1):

`>>` is right shift opperator.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_right-shift

`<=>` is Null safe comparator https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to