# prepared mysql query where value may be NULL

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm using node's `mysql` library and trying to do a query like so:

```
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ? AND field = ?`, ['a', value]);
```

The problem I'm running into is that sometimes `value = 1` but sometimes `value = null`.

From my testing, results only return when the query is written as `WHERE value IS null`  and doesn't work with `WHERE value = null`.

**Q**: How can I use the prepared query if the value may be null?

Comment: Why not just have two queries and an if statement to select between them in the case where value is null?

Comment: @EricYang is right. Handle the logic before you passed the query to MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to make you disappointed, but **YOU CANNOT**

You should use different comparative statement, which is

1. `WHERE value IS NULL`
2. `WHERE value = <your value>`

Regards to the Mysql Reference, null values are treated differently, furthermore null values are a missing values. So **You can't use arithmetic comparison for NULL**

Here is the reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: thanks - so I suppose I need to check `if (value === null)` and then use `=` or `IS` accordingly.

Comment: @d-_-b if you need null check then definitely you need to use  where values is null

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentioned spaceship operator `<=>`, it works with null-to-null comparsions

[Here is great spaceship operator description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21928508/2746472)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want try this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE IFNULL(name, 'null') = 'null' AND IFNULL(field, 'null') = 'null'`

But the next problem, you cannot fill your field with value 'null', or it will makes your query and data ambiguous.