# What is the difference between '<=>' and 'is' in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've been Google for a long time, and I feel there is no difference between the two statements.

```sql
# Query null value！
select name,birthdate from heros where birthdate is null;
select name,birthdate from heros where birthdate<=>null;
```

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/21927117/494134

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: `IS` operator against non-boolean causes error.

Comment: Or test, for example, `SELECT 2 <=> TRUE, 2 IS TRUE;`