# MySQL check if null if value is empty using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, null

I have multiple arrays similar to below.

```
{
  ["sku_original"]=>
  string(33) "98iuoo"
  ["po"]=>
  string(5) "9897"
  ["ca"]=>
  string(3) "557"
  ["cl"]=>
  string(5) "33"
  ["aa"]=>
  string(3) "80"
  ["ad"]=>
  NULL
  ["da"]=>
  string(4) "143.9"
  ["dr"]=>
  NULL
  ["cors"]=>
  NULL
}
```

I want to use `IS NULL` condition when a value is null in the array else I have to check `equal to` condition if not empty.
I have tried something like below.

```
$po =  $option['po'] != NULL ? $option['po'] : NULL ;
$ca =  $option['ca'] != NULL ? $option['ca'] : NULL ;
$cl =  $option['cl'] != NULL ? $option['cl'] : NULL ;
$aa = $option['aa'] != NULL ? $option['aa'] : NULL ;
$ad = $option['ad'] != NULL ? $option['ad'] : NULL ;
$da = $option['da'] != NULL ? $option['da'] : NULL ;
$dr = $option['dr'] != NULL ? $option['dr'] : NULL ;
$cors = $option['cors'] != NULL ? $option['cors'] : NULL ;
```

**The above code is not assigning value to a variable if option index is null
I also tried is_null.**

and SQL like below.

```
$sql = "SELECT abc FROM `abc` WHERE `po` = $po AND `ca` = $ca AND `cl` = $cl AND `aa` = $aa AND `ad` = $ad AND `da` = $da AND `dr` = $dr AND `dr` = '$dr' AND `cors` = '$cors' `sku` = '$sku' ";
```

I have to check `IS NULL` in SQL when value is null else I have to use `equal to`

Comment: Please share more details. Also, be warned that you should never use string concatenation to build SQL queries - they are vulnerable to SQL injections. Better use prepared statement

Comment: I'm not aware of string concatenation SQL and prepared statements. could you please share any links to learn more?

Comment: About prepared statements, if you use PDO: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and if you use MySQLi: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: thanks. I don't have additional details. I hope I have explained clearly

Comment: _Side note:_ For all those variable assignments, you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm) instead: `$po = $option['po'] ?? NULL;`

Comment: I'm not fluient in PHP, but isn't `$po =  $option['po'] != NULL ? $option['po'] : NULL ;` exactly the same as `$po =  $option['po']`? Why the more complicated expression? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in PHP there is type juggling so `!= null` effectively checks if something is _truthy_.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 1):

As you iterate your options variable (assuming you have already validated all of the keys using a whitelist of table column names), conditionally write a static `IS NULL` expression into the WHERE clause or a bound parameter with a non-null value.

```
// unconditionally include sku
$where[] = "sku = ?";
$params = ['s', $sku];
foreach ($option as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === null) {
        $where[] = "$key IS NULL";
    } else {
        $where[] = "$key = ?";
        $params[0] .= 's';
        $params[] = $value;
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT column_with_different_name_from_table
        FROM abc
        WHERE " . implode(" AND " , $where);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(...$params);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['column_with_different_name_from_table'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULL in prepared statements directly. Heres a dynamic way to build your query

```
// put all your variables in an array
$vars = array('po', 'ca', 'ab') ;

// iterate through and set up your key/value pairs
foreach ($vars as $var) {
  $val = (isset($option[$var]) && !is_null($option[$var])) ? $option[$var] : NULL;
  $q[] = " $var = ? ";
  $v[] = $val ;     
}

// set up the prepared statement
$query = "SELECT abc FROM `abc` WHERE " . implode(" AND " , $q) ;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$types = str_repeat("s", count($q)) ;
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$v);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you merely want optinal criteria, you can handle this in SQL by asking "is the parameter set, then use it, else don't".

```
$sql = "SELECT abc FROM abc WHERE (po = $po OR $po IS NULL) AND (ca = $ca OR $ca IS NULL) ...";
```

which can also be written as

```
$sql = "SELECT abc FROM abc WHERE po <=> COALESCE($po, po) AND ca <=> COALESCE($ca, ca) ...";
```

in MySQL (thus having each parameter only once in the query instead of having to use them twice).

**UPDATE:** I have focused on the SQL in above answer. It has been mentioned that you should not build the query string by concatenation, but use prepared statements and bind the variables. This is correct. I am not a PHP programmer, but it seems the difference in above assignments is mainly to replace the `$` with a `:`. Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT abc FROM abc WHERE po <=> COALESCE(:po, po) AND ca <=> COALESCE(:ca, ca) ...";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(":po", $option["po"]);
$query->bindParam(":ca", $option["ca"]);
...
$query->execute();
```

Comment: This is not satisfying the modern/professional standard.  Variables should not be injected into the sql string, but bound to placeholders in a prepared statement.  I did not expect to see this low-quality advice from a high-rep contributor.  This answer is also missing its education explanation.

Comment: More to the point, these variable injections will result in a rendered sql string that will have syntax errors.  When you write `null` values where you have them, the sql will just put a zero-length string there.

Comment: @mickmackusa: You are right of course. I just focused on the SQL, but of course one should not build the query string by concatenation, but use prepared statements instead As to the lines I am showing that means replacing the `$` with a `:`. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: For anyone not familiar with mysql's null-safe equals spaceship operator (not to be confused with php's three-way comparison spaceship operator): [What is this operator <=> in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21927117/2943403)

Comment: While I appreciate that you have modernized your answer, I believe your answer does not maintain the required logic.  If a given option value is `null`, then it should ONLY match a row where that null value exists in that specific column.  In other words, your answer will match `col = col` when the passed in value is null  -- this isn't right.  Am I clear in my feedback?

Comment: @mickmackusa: Ah, you may be right. I thought the OP wants optinal parameters, a common problem with SQL queries, where criteria must only be applied when given. Maybe they want to find null values when null is given instead. That would be `po IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $po` in standard SQL or just `po <=> $po` in MySQL