# Select if or Case column is empty

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table "messages"

```
['id', 'en', 'type', 'company_id']
```

i have two types

```
['new_contract', 'new_offer']
```

i may have two records with the same 'type' = 'type' but one with a company_id and one with a null 'company_id'

i want to select all records with company_id =1  but if one type is missing for this company get the missing type record even if it's null company_id

```
 record 1 ['1', 'new contract', 'new_contract','1']
 record 2 ['2', 'new offer', 'new_offer','2']
 record 3 ['3', 'new offer', 'new_offer',NULL]
 record 4 ['4', 'new contract', 'new_contract',NULL]

 Output
 record 1 ['1', 'new contract', 'new_contract', '1']
 record 3 ['3', 'new offer', 'new_offer', NULL]
```

Not sure if that's possible using sql `your text`

Answer (score 1):

This reads like a prioritization question, where, for each type, you prefer the row of company 1 over the row where company is null.

One option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select m.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by type order by company_id desc) rn
    from messages m
    where company_id = 1 or company_id is null
) m
where rn = 1
```

In the window function, `order by company_id desc` puts `null` values last - so this prioritizes the "other" type row, if any.

Answer (score 0):

To get all records of the company_id (if we have multiple rows of the same type) + the null records if there is a missing type, we can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE company_id=1 
    OR (company_id IS NULL AND type IS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(type) FROM table WHERE company_id=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show another option beside @GMB use of windowing functions -- you take all the items with null and all those without and union them to get a list you want (union will remove duplicates) like

```
SELECT id, type
FROM messages
WHERE company = 1

UNION

SELECT id, type
FROM messages
WHERE company is null
```

--

In the comments @islam Elbanna points out that you want to make sure you get all the types.  If this is the case then you just select all the types -- that would look like this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT id, type
 FROM messages
```

If you also want to know which ones have a entry for company 1 then you can do this

```
 SELECT base.id, base.type, c.company
 FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT id, type
   FROM messages
 ) as base
 LEFT JOIN messages as C on base.id = C.id and C.company = 1
```

Comment: AFAIU, returning the null records is only in case there is a missing type for this company_id

Comment: @IslamElbanna -- good point -- I added some additional queries if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

With this subquery, we will first obtain the company's type as well as any additional type that has not been assigned to a company:

```
select type, max(company_id) as company_id
from messages      
where company_id = 1 or company_id is null
group by type
```

Then we join it to the table to get the complete row :

```
select m.*
from messages m
inner join (
  select type, max(company_id) as company_id
  from messages
  where company_id = 1 or company_id is null
  group by type
) as s on s.type = m.type and s.company_id <=> m.company_id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MnByOkGf)

Comment: Thanks, @SelVazi Could you please explain why and s.company_id <=> m.company_id ?

Comment: and why max(company_id) ?

Comment: When the company is null, then NULL <=> NULL will yield to true, allowing the join to be matched and the NULL company row to be taken. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql#:~:text=is%20MySQL's%20null%2D,if%20one%20operand%20is%20NULL.

Comment: And because we are grouping by type, the company should be taken using max()/min() aggregate function, the max(company) will be 1 or null.